# Backbone.js: Fetching specific JSON sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js

I'm trying to build some foundations for a single page web app in Backbone.js. I've structured my JSON into "screens", with each screen being given an ID.

I would like to be able to render data from specific screens, both for the initial page load, and also after on.click events.

I've been trying to pass in an ID when I create a new model instance, but so far I'm getting erratic results: It is rendering different sections of JSON than I indicate, or simply rendering all of it. Any pointers on how to select a specific 'screen' (via its ID) would be greatly appreciated.

Here's an indicative JSON sample code:

```
[{
          "id": 0,
              "options": [ 
                { "text": "Tackle player", "next": [ 0, 1 ] }, 
                { "text": "Dribble the ball", "next": [ 1 ] }
              ],
              "results": [
                { "text": "Tackle successful", "next": [ 0 ] },
                { "text": "You are close enough to shoot", "next": [ 0, 1 ] }
              ]
            },



        {  
          "id": 1,
              "options": [ 
                { "text": "BLAH", "next": [ 0, 1 ] }, 
                { "text": "BLAH2", "next": [ 1 ] }
              ],
              "results": [
                { "text": "BLAH3", "next": [ 0 ] },
                { "text": "BLAH4", "next": [ 0, 1 ] }
              ]
        }

    ]
```

And here's my backbone code:

```
var app = app || {};

app.Screen = Backbone.Model.extend({
url: '/api',

parse: function(response){
    return response;
}
});

var Screens = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: app.Screen,
url: '/api'
});


app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize: function(parameters){

    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.addOne);

},


render: function(){
    this.$el.html("test");
    this.addAll();
    return this;
},


addAll: function(){
    this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
},  


addOne: function(model){
    var screen_view = new app.ScreenView({
        model: model});
    screen_view.render();
    this.$el.append(screen_view.el);

}

});



app.ScreenView = Backbone.View.extend({

template: _.template(

    '<ul id="options">' +
        '<% _.each(options, function(info) { %>' +
        '<li id="optionA"><a href="#"><%= info.text %></a></li>' +
        '<% }); %>' +
    '</ul>'
    ),

initialize: function(options) {
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
},
render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
}

});


$(function() {


var screen = new app.Screen({id:0}); //CURRENTLY BEHAVING VERY STRANGELY - change ID to 1 and you will get id 0 expected responses
app.screenCollection = new Screens([screen]);

app.screenCollection.fetch();

new app.AppView({
    collection: app.screenCollection, el: $('.gameWrapper')
}).render(); 


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just reference the array index in your parsed JSON data where `screens` is the array of screens:

```
var screen = new app.Screen(screens[index]);
```

The alternative is to use something like [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) to access the object based on the id which is a little more complicated.